# How to access nested ContentPicker field Content Items

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy, orchardcms-1.9

I have a single selection ContentPicker field that contains a custom ContentType, which in turn contains multiple 'child' content types.

I can get to the single content type in the ContentPicker using the code below:

```
var contentPickerField = (ContentPickerField) Model.ContentField;
var customContentType = field.ContentItems.First();
```

However I can't find a way of accessing the 'child' ContentItems that are associated with that ContentType instance. For example:

```
myCustomItem.ContentItems.Count()
```

causes a null reference exception and Shape Tracing doesn't seem to deep enough to give me the query path.

Any help much appreciated and sorry in advance for the description - it's super hard to explain!

Comment: Shape tracing is not the best way to find this, you should attach a debugger instead. On your content items, you need to access the field first: that `ContentItems` property doesn't exist on `ContentItem`.

Comment: Thanks @BertrandLeRoy - debugger & immediate window to the rescue! Once you can see the type that's being returned it makes a lot more sense. I'll post a fuller explanation when I've finished for others that might stumble on this...

Comment: Hi @ed13, you can use the IContentManager service to get the child content items.